# Solving natural convection equations (heat and flow) with the shooting method

Tags: python, numerical-methods, ode, fluid-dynamics

> TL;DR I've been implementing a python program to solve numerically equations for natural convection based on a particular similarity variable using runge-kutta 4 and the shooting method. However I don't get the right solutions when I plot it. Did I make a mistake somewhere ?

Hi !

Starting from a special case of natural convection, we get these similitude equations.
The first describe the fluid flow, the second describe the heat flow.
"Pr" is for Prandtl it's basically a dimensionless number used in fluid dynamics ([Prandtl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prandtl_number)) :

[image: blasius problem for natural convection]

These equations are subjects to the following boundary values such that the temperature near the plate is greater than the temperature outside the boundary layer and such that the fluid velocity is 0 far away from the boundary layer.

[image: boundary values]

I've been trying to resolve these numerically with Runge-Kutta 4 and the shooting method to transform the boundary value problem into an initial value problem. The way the shooting method is implemented is with the newton method.

However, I don't get the right solutions. 
As you can see in the following, the temperature (in red) is increasing as we are moving away from the plate whereas it should decrease exponentially.
It's more consistent for the fluid velocity (in blue), however the speed i think it should go up faster then go down faster. Here the curve is smoother.

[image: plot]

Now, the fact is that we have a system of 2 coupled ODE. However, right now, I'm only trying to find the one of the two initials values (e.g. f''(0) = a, trying to find a) such that we have a solution to the boundary value problem ([shooting method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_method)). Once found, I suppose we have the solution for the whole problem.

I guess I should maybe manage the two (f''(0) = a ; theta'(0) = b) but I don't know how to manage these two in parallel.
Last think to mention, if I try to get the initial value of theta' (so theta'(0)) I don't get the right heat profile.

Here is the code :

```py
"""
The goal is to resolve a 3rd order non-linear ODE for the blasius problem.
It's made of 2 equations (flow / heat)

f''' = 3ff'' - 2(f')^2 + theta
3 Pr f theta' + theta'' = 0

RK4 + Shooting Method
"""

import numpy as np
import math

from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.optimize import newton

from edo_solver.plot import plot

from constants import PRECISION

def blasius_edo(y, t, prandtl):
  f = y[0:3]
  theta = y[3:5]
  return np.array([
    # flow edo
    f[1], # f' = df/dn
    f[2], # f'' = d^2f/dn^2
    - 3 * f[0] * f[2] + (2 * math.pow(f[1], 2)) - theta[0], # f''' = - 3ff'' + 2(f')^2 - theta,
    # heat edo
    theta[1], # theta' = dtheta/dn
    - 3 * prandtl * f[0] * theta[1], # theta'' = - 3 Pr f theta'
  ])

def rk4(eta_range, shoot):
  prandtl = 0.01

  # initial values
  f_init = [0, 0, shoot] # f(0), f'(0), f''(0)
  theta_init = [1, shoot] # theta(0), theta'(0)
  ci = f_init + theta_init # concatenate two ci

  # note: tuple with single argument must have "," at the end of the tuple
  return odeint(func=blasius_edo, y0=ci, t=eta_range, args=(prandtl,))

"""
if we have :
f'(t_0) = fprime_t0 ; f'(eta -> infty) = fprime_inf
we can transform it into :
f'(t_0) = fprime_t0 ; f''(t_0) = a

we define the function F(a) = f'(infty ; a) - fprime_inf
if F(a) has a root in "a",
then the solutions to the initial value problem with f''(t_0) = a
is also the solution the boundary problem with f'(eta -> infty) = fprime_inf

our goal is to find the root, we have the root...we have the solution.
it can be done with bissection method or newton method.
"""
def shooting(eta_range):
  # boundary value
  fprimeinf = 0 # f'(eta -> infty) = 0

  # initial guess
  # as far as I understand
  # it has to be the good guess
  # otherwise the result can be completely wrong
  initial_guess = 10 # guess for f''(0)

  # define our function to optimize
  # our goal is to take big eta because eta should approach infty
  # [-1, 1] : last row, second column => f'(eta_final) ~ f'(eta -> infty)
  fun = lambda initial_guess: rk4(eta_range, initial_guess)[-1, 1] - fprimeinf
  # newton method resolve the ODE system until eta_final
  # then adjust the shoot and resolve again until we have a correct shoot
  shoot = newton(func=fun, x0=initial_guess)

  # resolve our system of ODE with the good "a"
  y = rk4(eta_range, shoot)
  return y

def compute_blasius_edo(title, eta_final):
  ETA_0 = 0
  ETA_INTERVAL = 0.1
  ETA_FINAL = eta_final

  # default values
  title = title
  x_label = "$\eta$"
  y_label = "profil de vitesse $(f'(\eta))$ / profil de température $(\\theta)$"
  legends = ["$f'(\eta)$", "$\\theta$"]

  eta_range = np.arange(ETA_0, ETA_FINAL + ETA_INTERVAL, ETA_INTERVAL)

  # shoot
  y_set = shooting(eta_range)

  plot(eta_range, y_set, title, legends, x_label, y_label)

compute_blasius_edo(
  title="Convection naturelle - Solution de similitude",
  eta_final=10
)
```

Comment: Replace `math.pow(f[1], 2)` with `f[1]**2`, this will automatically select the most appropriate power operation.

Comment: @MathieuRousseau Hello, I am trying to solve the same equation : did you succeed in fixing your code ?

Answer (score 0):

I could be completely off base here, but I wrote something similar to solve 1D fluid-reaction-heat equations. Try using [solve_ivp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html) and using the RADAU solver method, it helps with more difficult systems.

Also maybe try converting your system of ODES to a system of [first order ODEs](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/systemsde.aspx) as that may help.

Answer (score 0):

You are implementing the additional but wrong boundary condition `f''(0) = theta'(0)`, as both slots get the same initial value in the shooting method. You need to hold them separate, giving 2 free variables and thus the need for a 2-dimensional Newton method or any other solver for non-scalar functions.

You could just as well use the `solve_bvp` routine with a sensible initial guess.